# Операторы приведения в C++

Tags: c++, теория

Читаю сейчас "Discovering Modern C++", и есть там одно место, где автор пишет, что в С++ есть четыре оператора приведения (всем знакомые `..._cast`) и унаследованный из C оператор `(type)expr`.

В связи с этим очередной теоретический вопрос: автор забыл о приведении `type(expr)` или это приведение вообще говоря не является приведением, по сути являясь созданием объекта типа `type` из `expr`? ну, или применением оператора преобразования типа? Ведь вроде бы [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) говорится, что это тоже преобразование типа?

И еще - а есть ли вообще разница между преобразованием (conversion) и приведением (cast) или это синонимы?

И еще о лингвистике :) - у него четко различаются casting Up (от производного к базовому) и casting Down (понятно, наоборот)... Но что-то я в нашей литературе таких терминов раньше не встречал?

Comment: casting Up - восходящее приведение, casting Down - нисходящее приведение. Но я это встречал в основном в книгах по java.

Comment: @KoVadim и в плюсах тоже есть. Up - это по сути неявное преобразование (указателя или ссылки) к родительскому классу. Down - явное, в общем случае через `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> В связи с этим очередной теоретический вопрос: автор забыл о
>   приведении type(expr)

Это можно считать приведением(так пишет Майерс и другие называют это приведением), но в стандарте это не входит в список операторов приведения(cast operators). Т.е. формально, данный синтаксис не является синтаксисом приведения. Он в стандарте имеет своё имя: *functional notation*. В сущности, это создание объекта инициализированного `expr`. Это вызов конструктора.

> И еще - а есть ли вообще разница между преобразованием (conversion) и
>   приведением (cast) или это синонимы?

Первое это существительное, второе — глагол(чаще). Нет, разницы, с точки зрения языка, — нет.

> Но что-то я в нашей литературе таких терминов раньше не встречал?

Я нашу литературу давно не читаю, но если это перевод книги, в которой есть up-casting и down-casting, это не может быть не переведено.

---

Из стандарта про синтаксис из вопроса: 
**[expr.type.conv]p2**

> A simple-type-specifier (7.1.6.2) or typename-specifier (14.6)
>   followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the
>   specified type given the expression list. If the expression list is a
>   single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in
>   definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast
>   expression (5.4) <...>

Где *corresponding cast expression* это `(T)expression`

Comment: Спасибо! Просто я неоднократно читал в разной литературе о приведении `type(expr)` как о синониме для `(type)expr`. В конце-концов, ведь и `(type)expr` в C++ приведет к вызову конструктора, разве не так? Да, и книга - оригинал, на английском.

Comment: @Harry, там где эта конструкция работает, там они могут считаться синонимом, но штука в том, что только `(T)expr` описан в стандарте как оператор приведения, ни о каком `T(expr)` в описании операторов приведения и речи нет. Неформально и конструктор с одним параметром называется конструктором приведения.

Comment: Все же чисто логически между приведением типа и преобразованием разница есть. Например, `double` <=> `int` это явно *преобразование* (битовое представление существенно меняется), а `char *` <==> `void *` или `char` <=> `unsigned char` безусловно *приведение типа*. Где проводить границу? Это дискуссионный вопрос.

Comment: @avp, да нет тут никакой дискуссии. В стандарте языка эти термины используются почти взаимозаменяемо. С точки зрения логики, моей по крайней мере, изменение битового представление ничем не лучше изменение того, как то, что лежит в памяти будет интерпретироваться(сменили тип), только уровень абстракции разный.

Answer (score 4):

Выражение `type(expr)` не является приведением. Это создание нового объекта на основе `expr`, иногда может интерпретироваться как создание новой переменной

```
int(a); // создание переменной a
unsigned b = unsigned(a);  // создание нового объекта из a и инициализация b его значением
```

Разница между преобразованием и приведением есть. Приведение не влечёт за собой выполнения никакого кода, при преобразовании будет выполненный определённый код. При использовании кастов из С++ необходимо прочитать в [справке](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), какие конкретно действия будут выполнены.

Answer (score 3):

В [Мэйерс. Эффективное использование C++](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/c/978-5-94074-304-0/) автор считает конструкции `(T)e` и `T(e)` не имеющими "ощутимого различия, просто скобки расставляются по-разному".
Однако в "Страуструп. Язык программирования C++. Специальное издание. - М.;СПб.: Издательство БИНОМ - Невский Диалект, 2002" дается более сложное описание.
`T(e)` - создание значения типа `T` из значения `e` с помощью конструктора. Для встроенных типов эта запись эквивалента `(T)e`. Однако все-таки не до конца: преобразование указателей с ее помощью невозможно - написать `(char *)2` можно, а `char*(2)` нельзя.

Поэтому, на мой взгляд, это все-таки немного разные конструкции - приведение `(T)e` будет компилироваться всегда, в отличие от `T(e)`.

Comment: для раздумий https://goo.gl/Vsjk4q - для типов int-double разницы нет.

Comment: @KoVadim Функцию `f2` из https://goo.gl/OH9vJr конструкцией `T(e)` не записать. В первую очередь имел в виду это.

Comment: а я имел ввиду, что для простых типов генерируемый ассемблерный код идентичен.

Answer (score 2):

Преобразование типов может быть как явным, так и неявным.

**Явное преобразование называется приведением** (casting).

Чтобы в этом убедиться достаточно посмотреть на раздел **Index** Стандарта и увидеть там такие сноски:

> - conversion explicit type, see casting
> - explicit type conversion, see casting
> - type conversion, explicit, see casting

Явное преобразование типов описано в двух параграфах Стандарта`C++14`, названия которых начинаются с фразы **Explicit type conversion**, но имеют разное окончание:

- 5.2.3 **(functional notation)**;
- 5.4 **(cast notation)**.

При этом в п. 5.4/2 сказано:

> An explicit type conversion can be expressed using functional notation
>   (5.2.3), a type conversion operator (`dynamic_cast`, `static_cast`,
>   `reinterpret_cast`, `const_cast`), or the cast notation.

Т.о. явное преобразование может быть выражено через:

- функциональную нотацию: `T(e)`
- оператор преобразования типов: `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast` и т.д.
- нотацию приведения: `(T)e`

---

Функциональная нотация (относительно фундаментальных типов) разрешена только для простых спецификаторов типа (`char`, `double`, `int` и т.д.), но уже не будет работать с типами, записанными более чем одним словом (`unsigned char`, `long double`, `signed int` и т.д.).

Для классов функциональная нотация приводит к вызову конструктора соответствующего класса.

---

При использовании нотации приведения (Си-нотации) компилятор пытается выполнить следующие преобразования в указанном порядке:

- `const_cast`
- `static_cast`
- `static_cast` с последующим `const_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast` с последующим `const_cast`

В итоге будет выбран первый вариант, который удовлетворит требованиям соответствующего оператора.

По возможности следует избегать в коде на `C++` использования приведения в стиле Си. И отдавать предпочтение соответствующим `cast`ам для более четкого выражения своих намерений.